# Passing the user selection value from one activity to another

Tags: android, android-intent

I am making a small calculation game.

on the main screen there would be a RadioGroup

o Easy o Medium o difficult

Button Continue

then after the user selects this and presses continue then on next page another radio group

o Addition o Subtraction

Button Start

Now I want to display questions depending on the selection of radio buttons from there 2 activities.

How can I do that, for a single radio group I can use changeListener...But here I have to consider values from 2 radio groups simultaneously.

So how to do that. I tried my best to explain this using example and representation too.

Thanks

Comment: Pass the values between screens by adding the value as an extra to the Intent you use to launch it.  The new activity can then read the value from the intent.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable reply...It worked :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a bundle with Intent extras to pass data between activities.

```
Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putExtra("key", value);
i.putExtras(b);
startActivity(i);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtras(android.os.Bundle)

and in your SecondActivity

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringExtra(java.lang.String)

Comment: there are also methods getLongExtra(), getSerializableExtra(), etc.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and useful links, It worked and still I will go over through the links..

Answer (score 0):

For the apps that I've been involved with I've been using a [application object](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) to store state variables that need to be visible in more than one activity.  The application object gets created before any activity objects, and is the last thing to be destroyed when the application is closed, so it's a good place to store state variables.  You're allowed one application object per app, and the class type needs to be declared in the manifest.  It sounds like your difficulty variable and your add/subtract are state variables, so I'd suggest you go down this path.

Comment: Why this instead of Intent data?

Comment: As I said, I think this is good for state variables.  If I've misunderstood and the variables in question are not global state variables for the app then I agree that `Intent` is best.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to use the `SharedPreferences` if you want to save the value longer the current instance.

See for more details.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref